# How to get height of entire document in JavaScript on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a div with many absolute positioned elements inside it. Now I need to get the height of the document to be able to add a margin to the bottom.

This piece of code:

```
var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

works fine on desktop. However it doesn't work on mobile devices...

It returns the window height instead of the entire document height.

What I want to do is to add a margin to the bottom which doesn't work because of the absolute positioned elements...

Note:
Due to a strange behavior on tablets and smartphones where fixed elements on the left and right site moved I had to set my main containers overflow property to hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: due to the overflow: hidden it didn't get the entire document.

I solved the problem by searching for the lowest element on the document and adding a margin-bottom to it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try JQuery `height()` method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert("Height of document is: " + $(document).outerHeight(true));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Display the height of document</button>
```

Comment: I tried it and it returns the same value as the other methods

Comment: What do you mean 'the entire document height' ? `$(document)` is selecting the entire document

Comment: I have a div with absolute positioned elements which takes them out of the document flow so I think the document is smaller than what you can see in the browser. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Then try to change `height()` to `outerHeight(true)` - this selects height of an element with its all parameters: margin, padding and border.

Comment: I found the problem: to solve another problem I had with tablets and smartphones I had to set some divs to 'overflow: hidden' and 'overflow-scrolling: touch'... This caused my problem. As soon as I find the answer I'll update my question and answer it. Thanks for trying! :D